# Where is Microsoft.Sharepoint.IdentityModel.dll

Tags: security, sharepoint-2010, gac

I am trying to use the **SPFederationAuthenticationModule** class in my SharePoint Foundation 2010 project. \I cannot find **Microsoft.Sharepoint.IdentityModel.dll** file. There is not one in **c:\windows\assembly**. Help me!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1. start Command Prompt
2. write "cd  :\Windows\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Microsoft.SharePoint.IdentityModel\14.0.0.0__71e9bce111e9429c\"
3. write "copy Microsoft.SharePoint.IdentityModel.dll c:\"
4. now you can access the dll freely (e.g. copy to TFS, open with reflector or any other action)

Another option is to write "subst i: %windir%\assembly\gac_msil" in Command Prompt, that way you can browse the GAC_MSIL (where Microsoft.SharePoint.IdentityModel is located) via Windows Explorer.

Answer (score 17):

These answers are correct if you're using SharePoint 2010.

If you need to find the DLL for SharePoint 2013, you'll need to reference it from this location:
`C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Microsoft.SharePoint.IdentityModel\v4.0_15.0.0.0__71e9bce111e9429c\Microsoft.SharePoint.IdentityModel.dll`

Note that under .NET 4.0, the location of the GAC has changed.

Comment: Also note that the version changed when referencing it. 14.0.0.0->15.0.0.0

Answer (score 2):

for SharePoint 2013
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Microsoft.SharePoint.IdentityModel\v4.0_15.0.0.0__71e9bce111e9429c

Answer (score 1):

For SharePoint 2019, the location is:

```
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Microsoft.SharePoint.IdentityModel
```

Answer (score 0):

When you go to add the reference, you'll have to browse to C:\Windows\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Microsoft.SharePoint.IdentityModel\

Answer (score 0):

C:\Windows\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Microsoft.SharePoint.IdentityModel\14.0.0.0__71e9bce111e9429c\Microsoft.SharePoint.IdentityModel.dll

Answer (score 0):

When I searched for Microsoft.SharePoint.IdentityModel.dll on the server, it didn't find it, but when you add it as a reference and follow the path it works